# AngularJS ng-if and ng-class Toggle. Converting inline code to a function for ng-click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using `ng-include` to pull in a Bootstrap button w/dropdown menu. When I write an inline `ng-if`, the toggle doesn't work. I understand that I need to use `ng-click`. My question is how to convert the inline ng-if into a function.

I've converted this:

`<a href="" ng-click="isPreviewPanelOpen = !isPreviewPanelOpen">Image preview on/off</a>`

to

`<li> <a href="" ng-click="previewPanel()">Image preview on/off</a></li>`

The function I wrote is poor, and not working.

```
$scope.previewPanel = function() {

      isPreviewPanelOpen = !isPreviewPanelOpen;

    };
```

Here's the piece it controls (shows/hides). It works if I don't use and `ng-include`

`<div class="leftblock" ng-class="{'col-xs-12': isPreviewPanelOpen, 'col-xs-8': !isPreviewPanelOpen}">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be modifying the scope of the view (via `$scope`) in your function.

```
$scope.previewPanel = function() {
  $scope.isPreviewPanelOpen = !$scope.isPreviewPanelOpen;
};
```

Your current function is changing the value of some random variable (likely global).

Comment: That did it. Thank you Antiga! So `$scope` must be within the curly braces of a function. Sorry for the newbie questions. I appreciate the wisdom!

Comment: No problem. Please mark it as the answer only if it answered your question. Cheers!

Comment: Ok. Tells me I have 6 minutes to wait. Will do!